# Dependency is not satisfiable: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0)

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, dependencies

I am getting the following error code while trying to install the Chrome browser on a Linux/Gateway machine running Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0)
```

I'm presuming I should update something in my Library files, but the related online answers provide no clear direction into how to best locate those files and identify the errors, and what steps to take when those errors are found.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig-config
```

Nothing changed in the error message.

Comment: After updating my system I tried downloading the fontconfig1 file from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/177041650/libfontconfig1-dev_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb. And I'm getting a similar dependency error on the libfontconfig1 download. hahh. It now reads "Dependency is not satisfiable: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1)"

Comment: Just wondering... why are you using a 5 year old distro whose support is about to end in a week?

Comment: Good question egmont... I'd love to update to a newer operating system if I can be sure it won't wipe out my data. My backup drive just conked out on me, and I'd like to make sure everything is backed up before making an upgrade. So I'm going to have to wait for the repair, but I still need Chrome in the meantime...

Comment: Please upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1):

I installed 12.04.5 into a VM. It came installed with libfontconfig1 v.2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.

I tried to used synaptic to search font libfontconfig1, rt-mouse click and Mark for upgrade for it. It said that fontconfig-config also needs to be upgraded. The list also shows fontconfig itself to be upgradable. It however offered to upgrade them to only 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.2.

I tried downloading the current google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb. `dpkg -i` for it reported:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
  Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.8.0); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.6.3-1ubuntu5.
 google-chrome-stable depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1); however:
  Version of lsb-base on system is 4.0-0ubuntu20.3.
```

trusty has 2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libfontconfig1

It has multiple dependencies however:

```
libc6 (>= 2.14) [amd64]
libc6 (>= 2.7) [armhf, i386, powerpc]
libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1)
libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1)
```

If chromium is enough, 12.04.5 supports 37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.12.04.4

It also supports firefox 31.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

If those are not ok, I would suggest upgrading to trusty.